# I have two errors in a query PHP MySQL group by

Tags: mysql

I have this basic query`

```
SELECT * FROM contratti   GROUP BY mail
```

In MySQL I have this error:

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'databasesample.contratti.idcontr' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0):

to use GROUP BY you need to use aggregate functions like COUNT, SUM and so on.

See more examples
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

group by is for aggregated  result  ..(sum, avg , min, max)   and tipically a select * from .. is not a candidate for this kind of query ..

could be you are looking for an order by

```
SELECT * FROM contratti  ORDER BY mail
```

or for a valid group by function

```
select email, count(*)
FROM contratti  GROUP BY mail
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't use Mysqli but you can do that just like this via PDO;

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $username_db, $password_db);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contratti   GROUP BY mail";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```